# if...else issued: removing the matched variable

Tags: php, function, if-statement, logic

i am new to coding and can't establish idea for easy logic.. 
ok, I have written a code firstly have a look:

```
<?php
    function month_ana($mna){
        $c_mna = strlen($mna);
        echo "Let's Analysis <b>$mna</b> <br> Total Charectars: $c_mna <br>";
    }
    $go[0] = "January";
    $go[1] = "February";
    $go[2] = "March";
    $go[3] = "April";
    $go[4] = "May";
    $go[5] = "June";
    $go[6] = "July";
    $go[7] = "August";
    $go[8] = "September";
    $go[9] = "October";
    $go[10] = "November";
    $go[11] = "December";
    $fo = "October";
    $i = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++){
        if ($go[$i]==$fo){
            break;
        } else { 
            month_ana($go[$i]);
        }
    }
?>
```

what i wanna do is to delete the matched variable so, the function will skip it.
Let's see its output:

```
Let's Analysis January 
Total Charectars: 7 
Let's Analysis February 
Total Charectars: 8 
Let's Analysis March 
Total Charectars: 5 
Let's Analysis April 
Total Charectars: 5 
Let's Analysis May 
Total Charectars: 3 
Let's Analysis June 
Total Charectars: 4 
Let's Analysis July 
Total Charectars: 4 
Let's Analysis August 
Total Charectars: 6 
Let's Analysis September 
Total Charectars: 9
```

but problem is i have used `break();` statement so it stop working when variables matched in `October`, but i wish that, this will skip the matched variable not stop here, so in this case it should skip `October` and then start calculating again from `November` and continue. I hope u understand the problem. Any ideas?
If you think you should refer me some articles then please do, because i am very keen to learn PHP programming. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `continue;`

```
var $go = array('January', 'February', 'March', ...);

foreach ($go as $month) {
   if ($month == $fo){
      continue;
   } 
   echo $month . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: ah! thanks for that ,,, is there any way to compress the array ?

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer for assigning values to your `$go` array.

Comment: @JessicaLingmn if an answer helped you, then please press that green tick element on the document beside Tim Joyce answer and also press the upvote button :/

Answer (score 1):

use the keyword `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<=11;$i++)
{
  if ($go[$i] != $fo)
  {
    month_ana($go[$i]);
  }
}
```

I put '!=' instead of '=='.

If you use `continue` it will start the loop again, but you said you want to continue with November after having analysed October.